# Android 2.2.1 changelog

Tags: android, changelog

Is there a changelog available for Android 2.2.1?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be an official changelog, but here's a pastebin of the git commit log for Android "base" between the last version of 2.2 and the first (currently only) version of 2.2.1: http://pastebin.org/69434

I got this log by running the following command in [my checkout of the android source](http://source.android.com/source/download.html)

```
pretz@pretz-desktop:~/android-src/frameworks/base (froyo) $ git log android-2.2_r1.3..android-2.2.1_r1
```

**Update**: You can also find the git commit log for Android Base [on their gitweb instance](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=shortlog;h=ec721fd1db4d895b342cfb83c651e0b78afac4dd).  Everything that comes above the "android-2.2_r1.3" tag is new in 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

### From Verizon:

Added Data Widget to home panel.

- Improved Android™ OS Froyo stability.

### Improvements:

- Improvements to Microsoft® Exchange ActiveSync®:
- Enhancements to corporate email sync and push stop.
- PIN lock timeout now follows the server’s settings.
- Enhancements to SMTP authentication.
- Improvements to Visual Voice Mail:
- “Failed delivery to” message displays correctly when messages can’t be sent.
- Audio routes correctly to speaker, even when connected to a mono Bluetooth® headset.

### Other improvements:

- Device now supports MP3 media files after MR2 update.
- Music Play now runs smoothly and without lock-ups.
- Weather widget stays with assigned location updates, not current location.
- “Smart Profile: Face Down” feature will not permanently disable the phone’s ringer.
- Enhanced audio sync when playing high quality WMV videos.
- Improved video playback.
- Clearer colors assigned to soft keys in applications such as Google Maps.™

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find one anywhere, but I do know that it was released to block the exploit used by the one-touch root applications in the market.

Answer (score 0):

I too couldn't find it. 
My exchange email application showed a update notification stating that remote wipe is now possible and an option to choose yes no

Why is Google against rooting android? Afterall it is supposed to be open to all!

Comment: They are not "against" rooting.  They are against leaving gaping security holes in their OS, which happen to be used for rooting.  It is more of a security issue than a control issue (they aren't Apple!).

Comment: There is a difference between rooting and leaving a security hole open which is already being exploited (although for non-malicious purposes)